# Sql injection mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a dilemma how should I `mysql_real_escape_string()` my variables without inserting them into the database `\n, \r, \x00` when someone uses `" '` or `<br>` on my comment field, I tried with `preg_replace` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`, but seems I don't know exactly how to allow all the chars and signs I want.

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use str_replace to help with this:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n", "\x00", '"', '\''), '', $input));
```

Having said that, it is a good idea to switch to mysqli or PDO for database read / write. Both of these allow prepared statements, which reduce the risk of SQL injections.

Here's an example of PDO:

```
$stmt = $PDOConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO example_table (input_field) VALUES (:input_field)');
$stmt->bindParam(':input_field', $input);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_real_escape_string` only escapes values so that your queries don't break, it also protects against SQL injection if used correctly.

If you don't want certain characters you will need to use additional functions to strip them *before* you apply `mysql_real_escape_string`.

[insert obligatory "use prepared statements" comment]

Ex:

```
$string = "My name is
John";

$filtered_string = str_replace("\n", " ", $string); // filter
$escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($filtered_string); // sql escape
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` SET `message` = '" . $escaped . "'");
```

Comment: "[insert obligatory "use prepared statements" comment]"